# myBatis xml map causing namespace must be declared for element type mapper

Tags: xml, spring, mybatis

Is there anything obvious wrong with this setup please. On app startup I get Attribute "namespace" must be declared for element type "mapper", when it clearly is declared.

spring xml resource dao.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/JNDINAME"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>      
</bean> 

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapperScanner" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer"> 
    <property name="basePackage" value="com.mycompany.dao"/> 
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/> 
</bean>
</beans>
```

Interface:

```
public interface MyDAO {    
    public void save(@Param("id") String id);
}
```

Mapper xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>

<mapper namespace="com.mycompany.dao">

<typeAlias alias="xxxVO" type="com.xxx" />

<insert id="save" parameterType="string">
    SOME SQL etc
</insert>

</mapper>

</configuration>
```

The Interface is in `src/main/java/com/mycompany/dao`
The mapper xml in in `src/main/resources/com/mycompany/dao`

My pom has

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Actual error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Attribute "namespace" must be declared for element type "mapper".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:131)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:384)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:318)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.addDTDDefaultAttrsAndValidate(XMLDTDValidator.java:1275)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1940)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1363)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2756)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.XPathParser.createDocument(XPathParser.java:236)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure from where you copied but you have mixed up both `mybatis-config.xml` and `mapper.xml`

In mybatis-config.xml you define framework configuartions such as caching, define typealais, import mappers(not define mapper)

An example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
    PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
    "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>

    <settings>
        <setting name="cacheEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true" />
        <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true" />
        <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false" />
        <setting name="defaultExecutorType" value="SIMPLE" />
        <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="100" />
        <setting name="safeRowBoundsEnabled" value="false" />
        <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="false" />
        <setting name="localCacheScope" value="SESSION" />
        <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="OTHER" />
        <setting name="lazyLoadTriggerMethods" value="equals,clone,hashCode,toString" />
    </settings>

    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.kp.swasthik.domain" />
    </typeAliases>

</configuration>
```

And you define mapper in another xml( Note the difference in dtd)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="com.mycompany.dao.MyDao">

   <insert id="save" parameterType="string">
     SOME SQL etc
   </insert>

</mapper>
```

And in sessionFactory you set mybatis-config.xml and mapper file location(in below example I've place the all the sql file in sqlmap directory in classpath, alternatively you can define using mappers in mybatis-config.xml as shown [here](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html#mappers))

```
  <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:mybatis-config.xml"/>
        <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:sqlmap/*.xml" />
    </bean>
```

And in mapperscaner set the path of mapper interface package

Comment: Thanks Karthik, this fixed my many problems which I have spent some hours trying all manner of different solutions.